# Create an indicator flag based on column values of multiple columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the below data frame in pandas:

This table includes product details held by each customer.

- **Input Table:**

| Cust No | Product_1 | Product_2 | Product_3 | Product_4 | Product_5 | Product_6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | Red Apple | 0 | Green Apple | Pears | 0 | Watermelon |
| 102 | Watermelon | 0 | Pears | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 103 | Red Apple | Pears | Watermelon | Jackfruit | 0 | 0 |
| 104 | Pears | Green Apple | Watermelon | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 105 | Pears | Jackfruit | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I want to create a flag/indicator named "Apple_ind" which adds 1 or 0 based on the apple (Red or Green apples) product held by each customer. So the resultant data frame will be like:

- **Output Table:**

| Cust No | Product_1 | Product_2 | Product_3 | Product_4 | Product_5 | Product_6 | Apple_ind |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | Red Apple | 0 | Green Apple | Pears | 0 | Watermelon | 1 |
| 102 | Watermelon | 0 | Pears | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 103 | Red Apple | Pears | Watermelon | Jackfruit | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 104 | Pears | Green Apple | Watermelon | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 105 | Pears | Jackfruit | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) with [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) if need test exact match at least in one column:

```
df['Apple_ind'] = df.isin(['Green Apple','Red Apple']).any(axis=1).astype(int)
```

Alternative:

```
df['Apple_ind'] = np.where(df.isin(['Green Apple','Red Apple']).any(axis=1), 1, 0)
```

If need check `apple` substring use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) for non numeric columns:

```
df['Apple_ind'] = (df.select_dtypes('object')
                     .apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('apple'), case=False)
                     .any(axis=1)
                     .astype(int))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply the same process for all products, you can do:

```
import re

products = ['apple', 'pears', 'jackfruit', 'watermelon']
pattern = re.compile(fr"\b({'|'.join(products)})\b", re.IGNORECASE)
ind = (df.melt('Cust No', ignore_index=False)['value']
         .str.extract(pattern, expand=False)
         .str.lower().dropna())
ind = pd.get_dummies(ind).groupby(level=0).max().add_suffix('_ind')
out = pd.concat([df, ind], axis=1)
```

Output:

[image]